# Java if statement is stupid(simple)

Tags: java, string, comparison

Right, in this program I am supposed to be able to search for a person in the list. If I search for someone who is not in the list then the Found variable should be kept at false. If I search for someone who is in the list eg: "Ben" then Found should be set to true.

However for some reason, searching for someone who is in the list does not set found to true. It seems like the if statement which checks the player's input to the array is not working properly. I have no idea why this is. There are no errors. Can anyone help? Thanks

code:

```
    package com.test.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] Names = new String[4];
    Names[0] = "Ben";
    Names[1] = "Thor";
    Names[2] = "Zoe";
    Names[3] = "Kate";

    int Max = 4;
    int Current = 1;
    boolean Found = false;

    System.out.println("What player are you looking for?");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String PlayerName = scanner.nextLine();

    while(!Found && Current <= Max){
        //System.out.println(Names[Current-1]);
        //System.out.println("PLAYERNAME: " + PlayerName.length() + ", ARRAY: " + Names[Current-1].length());
        if(Names[Current-1] == PlayerName){
            //System.out.println("found");
            Found = true;
        }
        else{
            Current++;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(Found);
    if(Found){
        System.out.println("Yes, they have a top score");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No, they do not have a top score");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Read [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Use String.equals method instead of == for comparing string values

Comment: ...And you'll realize that `if(Names[Current-1] == PlayerName){` should be `if(Names[Current-1].equals(PlayerName)){`.

Answer (score 1):

String is Object and object equality checks with equals method.

`==` operator is used for object reference equality(means two reference is pointing to the same object or not!) or primitive(int, double, ...) equality.

```
if(Names[Current-1] == PlayerName)
```

should be

```
if(Names[Current-1].equals(PlayerName))
```

---

In this case there might be chance of getting `NullPointerExceotion` if `Names[Current-1]` is null. To avoid this situation java 7 provides a static Utility class [`java.util.Objects`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html).

> This class consists of static utility methods for operating on
>   objects. These utilities include null-safe or null-tolerant methods
>   for computing the hash code of an object, returning a string for an
>   object, and comparing two objects.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)

so the best way would be -

```
if(java.util.Objects.equals(Names[Current-1],PlayerName))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using String object which compare reference instead of value.

try:

```
if (PlayerName.equals(Names[Current-1])) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Names[Current-1].equals(PlayerName) instead of Names[Current-1] == PlayerName

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have knowledge on Collections but the following code would simplify your efforts. And the reason for the failure of above code is that you've used "==" instead of "equals". And for you information kid, always have a habit of using variables names starts with small letter eg. playerName

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add("Ben");
    names.add("Thor");
    names.add("Zoe");
    names.add("Kate");

    boolean found = false;

    System.out.println("What player are you looking for?");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String playerName = scanner.nextLine();

    for (String name : names) {
        if (playerName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            found = true;
    }
    // System.out.println(Found);
    if (found) {
        System.out.println("Yes, they have a top score");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No, they do not have a top score");
    }
}
```